# Bind keyboard layout changes to key-press (combination) on Linux and/or Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have recently come upon situations where it would be useful to quickly switch between different keyboard mappings. For example, sometimes I talk to my Danish friend and would like quick access to letters/symbols not available with my standard UK layout, such as ø or å, but it would take too long to go into the system settings every time. Anyone know a method of binding changes in keyboard layout to a keypress (combination) in Windows 10 and/or Debian/openSuse based Linux systems?

Update: ideally I would like to be able to bind to a single key-press.

Comment: Windows has the built-in key-combination for switching layout Windows+Space. This combination works in most Linux desktop environments, too.

Comment: Works for Windows but when I tried it on Tumbleweed it didn't work... Are you sure Windows key + Space works for Linux systems?

Comment: Have you enabled the keyboard layout in Region & Language settings?

Comment: I have checked in YaST but there appears to be no way to specify more than one keyboard layout at a time in the Tumbleweed system settings. (Though interestingly, I have found you can specify two languages at once for the system text -- I currently have a combination of Danish and English appearing in the menu screens! :oD)